# Customer mapping to store in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

In Magento , we can able to share the customer with website. is it possible to map the customer with store ?

I mean for customers has to be mapped with specific stores.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.
Customers can be either global or website scoped.
And it's not even a good idea to make the customer scope store view.
The store view is just a face of a website and you should not restrict on customer to a single store view (that can be a language or a certain currency).
A better way would be to have your store views under separate websites. Then you can achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We would like to map the particular products categories to the particular customers. How can we achieve it.